# Send DELETE request to collection endpoint

Tags: rest

How unrestful do you consider the following API:

```
/posts:  
  /{post-id}: 
    /likes:
      description: Collection of 'likes' that can be allocated to a post
      get:
        description: Get likes for a post
        is: [traits.pageable]
      post:
        description: Add a like to a post
      delete:
        description: Unlike a post (with queryParameter identifying the user)
```

Note that a `delete`request is sent to a collection (rather than an individual entity).
I don't see a point in having a single like resource in the form of:

```
/posts: 
  /{post-id}: 
    /likes/{like-id} => DELETE
```

Using a database like Mongodb, likes may as well - not have an id at all.

Comment: Just in regards to your last line, the backing dbms of your rest api should have zero bearing on how the API is interacted with. Also unrelated, but I don't think this is really a nodejs or a java question, since it's only asking about REST best practices.

Comment: @CollinD I agree, removed these tags. Also agree with the rest of your comment.